# ng-repeat search filter while using the input to add the data to db as well

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been trying to add a filter to my code to filter for each input that is on the top of my page, however, the filter is actually filtering for every property.

For example: If I search for a user in the user input field, the filter will actually filter the phone, role and status. I want to filter only the user if it is the user field or role if the text input is in role field.

I'm also using the same fields to add a user, so if the inputs are filled in and you click add, the data is added to the db which works but I'm having issues with the filter. I have searched and tried multiple things, however, it does not seem to work. If someone can point me to the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```
        <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.name" style="height:22px"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.phone" style="height:22px"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.role" style="height:22px"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.status" style="height:22px"></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="adduser(); showAlert($event)">Add</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="update()">Update</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="user in userdb | filter:user.name | filter:user.phone | filter:user.role | filter:user.status">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{user.role}}</td>
      <td>{{user.status}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="edit(user._id)">Edit</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="remove(user._id)" disabled>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.name" style="height:22px"></td>
  <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.phone" style="height:22px"></td>
  <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.role" style="height:22px"></td>
  <td><input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.status" style="height:22px"></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="adduser(); showAlert($event)">Add</button></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="update()">Update</button></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button></td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="user in userdb | filter:{name: user.name, phone: user.phone, role: user.role, status: user.status}">
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{user.role}}</td>
  <td>{{user.status}}</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="edit(user._id)">Edit</button></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="remove(user._id)" disabled>Remove</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I have tried this method and I just tried it again as per your suggestion though it doesn't display any data in the table when it loads. When attempting to filter any information, it doesn't seem to show anything. It almost seems like every field has to match.

Comment: The initial data is not displaying because you are not using the <table></table> tags. Put the rows inside table tags and it will work. I have updated the code.